# Pylinac の Picket Fence モジュールでファイル選択時にエラーが発生する

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

PythonのGUIを作成中です。
画像ファイルを選択し、PicketFenceというモジュールで解析したいと考えています。

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from pylinac import PicketFence

#ボタンがクリックされたら実行
def file_select():
  idir = r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ" #初期フォルダ
  filetype = [("DICOM","*.dcm"), ("ZIP","*.zip"), ("すべて","*")] #拡張子の選択
  file_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = filetype, initialdir = idir)
  input_box.insert(tkinter.END, file_path) #結果を表示
  

  pf_img = PicketFence(file_path())
  pf = PicketFence(pf_img)
  pf.analyze(tolerance=0.15, action_tolerance=0.03) 
  print(pf.results())
  pf.plot_analyzed_image()
  pf.publish_pdf('mypf.pdf')
           
#ウインドウの作成
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Python GUI")
root.geometry("360x240")

#入力欄の作成
input_box = tkinter.Entry(width=40)
input_box.place(x=10, y=100)

#ラベルの作成
input_label = tkinter.Label(text="結果")
input_label.place(x=10, y=70)

#ボタンの作成
button = tkinter.Button(text="参照",command=file_select)
button.place(x=10, y=130)
button = tkinter.Button(text='計算', command=PicketFence)
button.place(x=140, y=170)

#ウインドウの描画
root.mainloop()
```

というコードを作成したのですが、

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

というエラーが発生します。
どのように改善すべきでしょうか？
どなたかご教授お願い致します。

Comment: おそらく `pf_img = PicketFence(file_path())` で `file_path()`に`()` が付いているからでしょう。`()`を外して `pf_img = PicketFence(file_path)` にしてみてください。

Comment: `pf_img = PicketFence(file_path())` の行は必要ないので削除して、次の行の `pf = PicketFence(pf_img)` を `pf = PicketFence(file_path)` に変更してみて下さい。

Comment: 解決しているようですし、自己回答なさってはいかがでしょうか(自己回答は推奨されています)。現在この質問は未解決の質問に分‌​類されています。せっかくプラス評価されて‌​いる質問でもありますし、このままではもっ‌​たいないなと思いました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pf = PicketFence(pf_img)` 
`pf = PicketFence(file_path)`
変更することで上手くいきました。

ご指摘いただいたので自己回答させていただきます。

Comment: 自己回答でも解決済みであればためらわずに解決にしてくださいね。それでQAとして完結します（緑色になる）ので。